# Querying calendar list through SharePoint lists web service.

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, calendar

I'm trying to query the SharePoint calendar list through lists web service to get all the event that occurred in the current month. The results that I'm getting are very intermittent. I'm not facing any the same problem when queried with SharePoint object model. I have pasted the code below. Can any one please help me on this? Thanks.

```
 var soapEnv =
  "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
        <soapenv:Body> \
             <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                <listName>Calendar</listName> \
                <query> \
                  <Query> \
                    <Where> \
                      <DateRangesOverlap> \
                       <FieldRef Name='EventDate' /> \
                       <FieldRef Name='EndDate' /> \
                       <FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' /> \
                       <Value Type='DateTime'><Week /></Value> \
                      </DateRangesOverlap> \
                    </Where> \
                  </Query> \
                </query> \
                <queryOptions> \
                 <QueryOptions> \
                  <ExpandRecurrence>True</ExpandRecurrence> \
                  <CalendarDate>" + calendarDate + "</CalendarDate> \
                 </QueryOptions> \
                </queryOptions> \
            </GetListItems> \
        </soapenv:Body> \
    </soapenv:Envelope>";
```

Comment: "The results that I'm getting are very intermittent" How so - what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Declare ...
   string ddate = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(calendarDate );

and use ddate as a input in CAML Query ..

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this line?

```
<Value Type='DateTime'><Week /></Value>
```

I think it should be

```
<Value Type='DateTime'><Month /></Value>
```

Note that it will also return the events of some days from the end of the previous month, and some events from the beginning of the next month.